# Please suggest me a good server configurations for VOD platform

Tags: linux, configuration

I need a suggestion to get good server for VOD platform, Using Linux "top" command I identified one httpd process is taking 0.3 CPU as well as MEM usage,and all the movies streamed are HD (min 5Mbps) I am having 2000 customers, I want to put a server to meet this requirement and secondarily in that server how much processors,Memory and NIC I need to have.

Please suggest me a good server configurations for VOD platform. (Also if possible online purchase link)

Thank you,

S.Sundar

Comment: 1) This is not quite right place to post this, but while you are here, we can give you some tips anyway.

2) Don't post minimum bitrate. To calculate, you will need to know mean or, even better, maximum one.

3) What protocol are you using HTTP, RTSP, RTMP?

4) If you use HTTP, is it plain 1-rate file hosting or ABR via HLS?

5) If you are using RTSP or RTMP, what software are you streaming from?

Comment: sorry i was not aware of this. maxmimum bitrate is 6mbps, i am using plain http streaming.

Answer (score 1):

In case of maximum load (all 2000 customers connect simultaneously):

```
2000 x 6Mbps = 12 Gbps
```

If we take into account, that no NIC can work on its full load for a long time, this gives us 2x10GBps interfaces

As for RAM, each connection will need 8-10mb so:

```
2000 x 10mb = 20Gb -> 32Gb (as you will need some for system processes too)
```

HDD: You haven't said, how big is your library, but i guess 4x2TB will be more then enough. That gives us

```
(4+1)x2TB = 8TB HDD on RAID 5
```

CPU: this is quite a load to handle, so you will have to use at least 32 logical cores to handle it. Take couple of Xeons of a recent series. Nothing too expensive, but with plenty of cores.